# The wait operation timed out in devexpress report

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, dataset, devexpress

Description:

> An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out

Source Error:

```
Line 1399:                dataTable.Clear();
Line 1400:            }
Line 1401:            int returnValue = this.Adapter.Fill(dataTable);
Line 1402:            return returnValue;
Line 1403:        }

Source File: c:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\8562cbc5\e7d18687\App_Code.ilsptr20.77.cs    Line: 1401 

Stack Trace: 


[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out]

[SqlException (0x80131904): Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +212
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +81
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +631
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +4234
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() +58
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +89
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted) +438
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest) +2620
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry) +1635
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +64
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +244
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +37
   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +10
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +138
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +157
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable) +106
   DSFinalPercentageTableAdapters.spTotalPercentageTableAdapter.FillByClass(spTotalPercentageDataTable dataTable, Nullable`1 classid, Nullable`1 eng) in c:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\8562cbc5\e7d18687\App_Code.ilsptr20.77.cs:1401
   xpTotalPercentage.xpTotalPercentage_BeforePrint(Object sender, PrintEventArgs e) in f:\Slim\App_Code\xpTotalPercentage.cs:452
   DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XRControl.OnBeforePrint(PrintEventArgs e) +262
   DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XtraReport.OnBeforePrint(PrintEventArgs e) +304
   DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XtraReport.TryCreateDocumentCore(Single progressRange, Boolean buildPagesInBackground) +44
   DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XtraReport.TryCreateDocument(Single progressRange, Boolean buildPagesInBackground) +78

[Exception: Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.]
   DevExpress.XtraPrinting.PrintingSystemBase.OnCreateDocumentException(ExceptionEventArgs args) +175
   DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XtraReport.TryCreateDocument(Single progressRange, Boolean buildPagesInBackground) +298
   DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XtraReport.CreateDocument(Boolean buildForInstantPreview) +12
   DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XtraReport.CreateDocument() +15
   Forms_StudentFinalPercentageReport.getReport() in f:\Slim\Forms\StudentFinalPercentageReport.aspx.cs:122
   Forms_StudentFinalPercentageReport.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in f:\Slim\Forms\StudentFinalPercentageReport.aspx.cs:23
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +85
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +79
   System.Web.UI.Adapters.ControlAdapter.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +12
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +98
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2853
```

Comment: The query is taking more than the default 30 seconds to complete.  You need to increase in the SQL Command the default timeout from 30 seconds to a larger time period.

Comment: I increased command timeout 1000